# Autolayout content view background does not resize

Tags: background, autolayout, scrollview

I made a dynamic data view with constraints. Once the data loaded into the form the form is updating its size properly in the scrollview's content view. But I cannot get the background color properly resized. The grey background remains the same size as it is at design time.

[image: Picture of the content page]

```
func fillFormWithData() {
    dispDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advdescription"]
    dispLongDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advlongdesc"]
    priceandcurrency.text = jSonData[0]["advprice"]! + " " + jSonData[0]["advpricecur"]!
    contentview.layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: validitydate.frame.origin.y+validitydate.frame.height+50)

    scrollview.contentSize = contentRect.size
}
```

The contentview is resized properly, but the background remains the same height as during load.

Links to the interface builder setup.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var dispDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dispLongDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceandcurrency: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var validitydate: UILabel!
```

In the interface builder the size of the contentview is constraint to the scrollview bottom.

Comment: Show the relevant code please.

Comment: Added to code section, where I refresh the form data and the layout.

Comment: Ok. Can't tell much from this, you'll have to show your code where you set up your views too. Looking at this, it seems like you are doing everything with frames, so you might need to update background frame also.

Comment: The view is completely setup in the interface builder with all their constraints. Contentview is an UIView within the scrollview itself and all outlet is linked into the class definition. I add this to the above.

Comment: Shouldn't you be changing the frame of the contentView also then?

Comment: I have tried it, but the background portion which is not visible during load remains white, instead of the rest which is set to grey. I have tried to change the content view bounds as well, not solving the issue.

Comment: Finally I have changed the scroll background to the desired colour and left the content backgrounds transparent. It works now as planned, however it is still not clear for me why the view inside the scrollview could not be changed dynamically.